# Working with TFS and Odata

Tags: tfs, odata

I am working with Odata and TFS.  I was able to get the OdataTFS file downloaded and working.  I am trying to write a client console application that will access TFS so I can run queries againest it.   I am trying to figure out this line

```
  var tfsData = new TFSData.TFSData(new Uri("https://codeplexodata.cloudapp.net");
```

The way I usually access information on TFS is to into visual studio 2010, click connect to TFS Server, type in the server name and thats it.  But here I am unsure how to do it.  I haven't found any materials on how to connect to a server rather than to a codeplex.  Where would I find the uri for this? Any help anything at all would be great, i have read the first 15 google searches on odata and still a little lost.

Answer (score 0):

TFS does not have any OData services included in the installation.

You need to install the [OData Service for Team Foundation Server](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/briankel/archive/2011/10/26/odata-service-for-team-foundation-server-2010-v1.aspx) on your local TFS server in order to use OData against your on-premises TFS.

Comment: I have multiple instances of the TFS, which make it difficult to deploy odata on all TFS servers..I wanted a user to be able to come in choose there TFS, and then just pull all there stories..and maybe add a small query if they wanted to find just one user stories.  Is this even possible with a third party application or is this something I need to create from scratch?  Any help is greatly appreciated

Comment: I would target the TFS SDK for this - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb130146(v=vs.80).aspx - instead of using the OData services.  Working with OData has the advantage of being a bit easier to get started with, but the TFS SDK has the advantage of being able to work on any server without installing additional components.  Plus there are many knowledgeable people in the stackoverflow community who are happy to answer questions about the TFS SDK.

Comment: FWIW, the TFS OData team (not that they're unbiased) strongly recommends against doing that. As I understand it, the TFS services are unsupported and can change over time.

Comment: @DaveNichol - sorry, the OData team recommends against doing *what*?